# Allowed to post scanned page from text book on SE

Tags: discussion

Am I permitted to upload a page from a textbook on SE?

Comment: ...why would you want to?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the book?

Comment: @Shog9 Becuase there is multiple paragraphs from the book and charts from multiple previous pages that show inheritance.

Answer (score 14):

No. Not even considering copyrights at the moment, we still **don't want you to**.

Images aren't SEO friendly. We'd much rather you type everything out, so it is all searchable. Worse, if the image goes missing, the entire context of your question is gone. So no, don't upload an image as your question. Images are for providing examples, not a shortcut to not having to type anything.

Answer (score 7):

> Becuase there is multiple paragraphs from the book and charts from multiple previous pages that show inheritance.

I'd say only scan the charts.  I don't know what your specific question will turn out to be, but I think that succinctly *summarizing* the paragraphs of text in your own words may actually give you a head start toward understanding the material, and it will give a skimmable overview for those who will be answering your question (many people have probably read these same textbooks and few will care to wade through a wall of text to understand your problem).

Try to put yourself in the position of someone reading your question and think about which would be the most informative data to present about the problem at hand.