# Accessibility and Tables - Could we borrow the Markdown syntax used by Jira or similar?

Tags: feature-request, accessibility

In the excellent question *[Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/349643)* it was rightly highlighted in the answers that text, code and mathematical expressions in images cannot be read by screen readers.

When asking and answering questions concerning data in tables, such as *[Creating Attendance Sheet from acces control output](https://superuser.com/q/677821/581166)*, you are forced into the nasty text extrapolation such as that put together in the question, or using Markdown, for which you can use a Markdown table generator such as *[Markdown Tables generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)*.

The trouble with Markdown tables is that when they are wide, they can break like shown here

> | Super wide column | Super wide column | Another super wide column |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Unless the Markdown content is tabbed to turn it into a code block as shown here

```
| Super wide column | Super wide column | Another super wide column | | |
|-------------------|-------------------|---------------------------|---|---|
```

But then on mobile screens, this table is so wide, it goes off (overlaps) the side of the screen.

Then I found out about [Jira’s Markdown syntax](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables) through [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51478528/3198356) which outputs an HTML table. Surely this would be more accessible for those with screen readers?

In the comments it is highlighted that tables have always been banned on Stack Overflow due to their habit of being able to completely cause havoc in the page layout.

> This was specially true when the pages still used tables to do their layout.

[Tables are not encouraged for html page layout purposes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/why-arent-we-supposed-to-use-table-in-a-design/6037), but tables are useful in STEM sites such as [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com) or [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com) when conveying certain information in a concise format or displaying certain data.

WebAIM has [a good write-up](https://webaim.org/techniques/tables/) on the accessibility issues surrounding badly formed tables on the web.

It is also highlighted in the comments that Jira is a helpline/ticketing software and we wouldn’t be able to use it as such, but surely we could maybe borrow the Markdown methods? Would it be a major issue if we were to move into using methods used by Jira (or similar, such as [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/1.0/WikiFormatting)) on Stack Exchange in order for questions relating to data tables to be able to be formatted better?

Comment: On SO at least, questions that involve table data are often about code that reads that data as input, or produces it as output. If it's input then it's desirable that the data is directly readable by the code. That makes it easier for answerers to verify that their code behaves as intended. A good way to achieve that is for the OP to provide a small program that produces the desired input data, eg as a string or simple CSV file.

Comment: tables have always been banned on SO due to their habit of being able to completely cause havoc in the page layout. This was specially true when the pages still used tables to do their layout. With the new responsive vibe maybe this argument no longer holds true. If anything, SE was planning to move to CommonMark as their preferred markdown. I haven't checked if common mark has table support baked in.

Comment: Jira is a helpdesk/ticketing software/ We can't use it.  In theory, their flavour of markdown could be copied, or allowing html tables could be used but it might be more practical to rescoping this form "can we use (totally different software)" to "Can we borrow the ways that software does it?"

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding. Yes, a good idea for editing in this case. I will get onto it.

Comment: I'd love tables, but I'm not sure what advantage Jira's MD tables have over Github's.