# Add Table Generator link as part of the help in SO Editor for generating tables using markdown format or embed it in the SO Editor

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor, stacks-editor

This feature request was [posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420690/add-table-generator-link-as-part-of-the-help-for-writing-question-answer-for-cre) in Meta Stack Overflow, it was pointed out that this feature (adding the [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) link or embedding the tool) was not considered in the new version of the SO Editor. In short the suggestion is:

1. Provide [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) link as part of contextual help or/and SO support pages. (Solution with minimal effort) or
2. **Optimal solution**: as an embedded element (this tool or any other similar one) in the editor for questions/answers to generate the table in markdown format.

Here is a screenshot for entering the tables values and the output generated, then just copy to the clipboard and paste it in SO question/answer section.

[image: sample of Table Generator UI]

It also provides the *Compact mode*, so the information is not indented, it removes all the extra spaces added.

[image: compact mode]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345584/accessibility-and-tables-could-we-borrow-the-markdown-used-by-jira-or-similar

Comment: As much as I used to use it, that site is pretty user unfriendly. I copy tables and it puts everything in the first cell. I especially struggled to use it on mobile. (Nowadays I use Regex101 to generate tables — it works no matter the format of the original table, at the expense of requiring a tiny bit of tinkering and expertise in regex.)

Comment: @Laurel I didn't have that user experience, but it is true that I used it from my computer, not mobile device. Would you share the link to the Regex101 for generating markdown tables. I used this link for testing regular expressions, but not for generating tables.

Comment: @rene yes it sounds similar, they proposed a similar feature from Atlassian (Jira). What brought my attention is that this suggestion was posted more than two years ago, and no action since then. Some moderator didn't consider it because it is a tool from Jira for internal purpose, but it didn't trigger other action to improve table markdown generation process. I hope this time it will have more attention.

Comment: @Laurel did you try to mark the option: Compact Mode? this may help reading the information in other devices.

Comment: Compact mode doesn't make it work. [Table generator puts everything in the first cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ3dH.png). As for Regex101, the regexes are different for each input, eg `^ *|  +|$`. I have to make tweaks to the input text so it generates the line between the header and body of the table. See an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tPqm.png), & [live post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90720/191178). (No Regex101 isn't helpful for most people. But this may give you an idea of how unusable I find other sites that are supposed to convert copied text to markdown tables.)

Comment: While I would support providing additional help in generating Markdown tables, I don't support linking to a specific non-SE site which isn't controlled by SE to provide such a conversion service. That you link to the site twice and have posted this on two sites makes it feel promotional. That may not have been your intent, but it's certainly the feel I get, particularly when what you are advocating for is for SE to officially link to that specific site from every page on which the editor is shown.

Comment: @Makyen currently the contextual help for answer/question provides a link to a non-SE: [GitHub-flavored markdown format.](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-), which is not really useful or easy to read as a help

Comment: @DavidLeal At least to me, there's a substantial difference between linking to a page on GitHub which explains GitHub-flavored Markdown and some other ad-supported site (one of many that supply similar functionality).

Comment: @Makyen my point is how to improve the existing documentation to minimize the impact of having so many questions with screenshots for simple tables or to simplify the process for generating such tables. I saved a lot of time once I found Table Generator, but until then it took me a lot of time, so I would like to improve the help so other people can have the same information I had now improving the documentation of the help for table markdown generation.

Comment: @Laurel I tested it, it works great, here is a [sample](https://regex101.com/r/7OCaIK/1). It saves more spaces than Table Generator because it trims the space between `|`, but it converts sometime the two spaces `  `  to `. `, I don't know why. I think it is a good approach when you populate the data from scratch, but if you have the data in Excel/Google, with Table Generator you can copy the entire range, by columns or rows. All such possible alternatives to generate table markdown should be documented in the help for generating such tables.