# What can and cannot be implemented in the advice guideline for new users?

Tags: support, user-interface, asking-questions, site-specific

Context: Chemistry SE is going through changing their [interface shown to new users](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/proposals-for-customizing-guidance-presented-to-first-time-askers)

When a new user decides to write their first question, they are greeted with this pop up,

[image]

My question, is what can be added to this guideline page? Are things like MathJax, multiple lists allowed within the advice page?

Comment: What do you think should be added?

Comment: I just wanted to know what could be added, Chem SE is going through a make over of this page

Comment: I think you need to propose something or some categories of thing and then the developers can comment on feasibility.

Comment: This content is not something users or even moderators can edit, I don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/proposals-for-customizing-guidance-presented-to-first-time-askers

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I know that only staff can modify this. However we were going through the steps in order to change this advice page

Comment: So go through the steps then your moderators will ask for it to be implemented. Developers are unlikely to comment about how feasible something is till there's something concrete to comment on.

Comment: The content in your picture does not appear to come from the Help of Chemistry SE - https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=%22asking+a+good+question%22 - please provide a link to it.

Comment: @PolyGeo Open ask questions in incognito mode and you'll see it pop up

Comment: If history has predictive power, there is [a list of changes and accepted proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) that might or might not be interesting (or comprehensive enough).

Comment: Evidence points to it being full markdown (there is a bulleted list on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)). I don't know if that includes plugins like MathJax. I'm also not sure that you really need those plugins since this popup is supposed to be a brief introduction to the site.

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: Related: [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/289691)

Comment: @Rubén: Indeed. I'd argue this is a duplicate of that Q&A; Catija's answer there even addresses what kinds of formatting, etc. can be used in the customizable portions of that modal. (Notably, [SpencerG's answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5241/115331) to the Chemistry Meta question linked in another comment above includes a link to that MSE Q&A already.)

Comment: @V2Blast (cc @Ruben), the question is not what can be modified, it's how it can be modified. What are the limitations to the changes in the modal page text?

Comment: Also, it was more of a generic question, since I assume the ways this can be modified is consistent through the network.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal: The limitations (including what formatting can be used in the customized parts of the modal) are also mentioned in Catija's (self-)answer to the Q&A that Rubén linked. For "Replacing the "You're ready to ask ..." text", full HTML can be used. For "Adding text before the bullets", only mini-markdown can be used ("essentially the markdown limited to comments - so bold, italics, and links").