# Screenshots in posts referring books

Tags: feature-request

**Please add search indexing to screenshots.**

As a physics student, it is more than natural to come upon some doubts while reading a standard textbook. When asking questions in PSE about that specific doubt, the natural response will take a screenshot of the page and describe the issue in detail. That is exactly how I would ask my questions to my peers. There are many such questions from new users where I can see a "Do not post screenshots" comment being posted under them.
If I understand it correctly, writing out the question in text makes the indexing part easier for the search algorithm.

But in my opinion, the long-term goal of a website, or any service for that matter, should be to become the **least obstructive as possible to the user**. The service should silently exist and just work how anyone would naturally expect them to work. I think the long-term solution to this problem is not to discourage the use of screenshots but to incorporate search indexing for text inside photos. My google photos already does this. Wouldn't it be great if this website could do that too? I don't know how practical or realistic this is for now, but I know for a fact that user-friendliness would lead to more users in the long term.

Comment: search indexing based on *what* though? - including alt text might be a reasonable way but unless SE scans through and 'good enough' and OCRs any images with text, and OCR is still pretty imperfect, it seems impossible

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: *[Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)*

Answer (score 9):

Taking a screenshot of a book would be a violation of the author's copyright. Take the time to write your question in your own words instead. You can and should explain exactly what it is that you don't understand.

If you really need to, you can quote a few words from the book but you'd need to mention its authors and make it clear which words are quoted and from which book. Simply sticking a screenshot in your question even if we somehow provide an OCR version of its text is not going to do that.

Comment: Come on, quoting even a whole paragraph is usually well within the limits of fair use. While paraphrasing can introduce distortions of meaning due to misunderstandings on part of the paraphraser. I have [seen it happen](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/26202/15334).

Comment: The OP says a page, not a paragraph. We have lots of problems already with people who simply don't or won't understand copyright. Here's my example, [likely most of 900 answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423991/deletion-of-plagiarism-posts)